# Generating unique variables for #each in an array in order to write an upvote/downvote app

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am brand new to coding so forgive my very obvious ignorance. My question is this: How can I create a unique variable for each item in a global array in MongoDB so that I can tally upvotes and downvotes and sort accordingly. I'm doing all this in the Meteor framework.

Here's my code:

```
<template name="website_item">
 <li>
  <a href="{{url}}">{{title}}</a>
  <p>
   {{description}}
  </p>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default js-upvote">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true">             </span>
  </a>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-default js-downvote">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true">       </span>
 </a>
 <p>
   Votes: {{totalVotes}}
 </p>
</li>
</template>
```

Here's my client.js:

```
var totalVotes = 0;

Template.website_item.events({
    "click .js-upvote":function(event){
        // example of how you can access the id for the website in the      database
        // (this is the data context for the template)
        var website_id = this._id;
        console.log("Up voting website with id "+website_id);
        // put the code in here to add a vote to a website!
        totalVotes++;
        console.log(totalVotes);
        Websites.update({_id:website_id}, {$set:      {totalVotes:totalVotes}});
        return false;// prevent the button from reloading the page
    }, 
    "click .js-downvote":function(event){

        // example of how you can access the id for the website in the     database
        // (this is the data context for the template)
        var website_id = this._id;
        console.log("Down voting website with id "+website_id);

        // put the code in here to remove a vote from a website!
        totalVotes--;
        console.log(totalVotes);
        Websites.update({_id:website_id}, {$set:     {totalVotes:totalVotes}});
        return false;// prevent the button from reloading the page
    }
})
```

In collection.js I have:

```
Websites = new Mongo.Collection("websites");
```

and in server.js I have:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(() => {
    // code to run on server at startup
    if (!Websites.findOne()){
        console.log("No websites yet. Creating starter data.");
          Websites.insert({
            title:"Test site", 
            url:"http://www.test.com", 
            description:"This is a test.", 
            createdOn:new Date(),
        totalVotes: 0
        });


        Websites.insert({
            title:"Google", 
            url:"http://www.google.com", 
            description:"Popular search engine.", 
            createdOn:new Date(),
        totalVotes: 0
        });
    }
});
```

I hope i've been comprehensive and clear with my question. I just want to be able to save up and downvote tallies for each item in my global array but right now there's just a single variable which does nothing for me.

Thanks so much!

Comment: If you convert your array to a collection then you can have a unique `_id` for each document (row). Also use `$inc` instead of increment and `$set` because with your approach two simultaneous votes might give the wrong result.

Comment: Thanks Michel. This was helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're missing publish and subscribe. the idea is your template will subscribe to the website data, and the server will then publish what you're asking for. you would write a helper that performs a find() on the published data, and an #each loop that would iterate over that data.

once you're done that, the tricky part, which is what you're asking about, is to tag each loop item so that, when clicked, you can uniquely identify it in the event handlers.

let's set up a new template (i'm writing all this code just in this text box, w/o trying it, so please forgive typos):

```
<template name="Websites">
    {{#each website in websites}}
        {{website.title}}
        Votes: {{website.totalVotes}}
        <button class="js-upvote" data-id={{website._id}}>Vote Up</button>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

then, you need to subscribe, like this:

```
Template.Websites.onCreated(function() {
    this.subscribe('websites');
});
```

i'll assume you already have a publish written, or auto publish is on...

then write the helper:

```
Template.Websites.helpers({
    websites() {
        return Websites.find({});
    }
});
```

and finally the event listener that can identify which item was clicked:

```
Template.Websites.events({
    'click .js-upvote': function(event, template) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event && event.currentTarget && event.currentTarget.dataset) {
            let websiteId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
            // now you can save the incremented votes for this website
        }
    }
});
```

Regarding your totalVotes variable, i think i understand what you're trying to do, and now you can get rid of that. with the code i've written, it will save to the db the increments and decrements of each website, and because you're subscribed, you'll get that updated vote total back and reactively display it in the template.

**update:**

alternatively, accessing _id without writing it to the DOM:

```
<template name="Websites">
    {{#each website in websites}}
        {{website.title}}
        Votes: {{website.totalVotes}}
        <button class="js-upvote">Vote Up</button>
    {{/each}}
</template>

Template.Websites.events({
    'click .js-upvote': function(event, template) {
        event.preventDefault();

        let websiteId = this._id;
        // now you can save the incremented votes for this website
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: There's no need to write the `_id` to the DOM. `this._id` in the event handler will give you the `_id` of the item that was clicked on.

Comment: @MichelFloyd does that work for you 100%? i thought my team had run into a situation where this._id wasn't right, so we started writing it to the DOM.

Comment: I haven't seen it not work but often I put the lowest level object in its own template, I find that cleaner for event handling.